# Submitting from from Colorbox iframe to parent window

Tags: jquery, forms, colorbox

I'm pretty new to colorbox and lovin-it. I've been trying to submit a
form from Colorbox iframe to parent window but haven't had any luck.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code.

```
$('#CustomizeBuy').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('action','customize-order.cfm');
    parent.location.submit();
    parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
});
```

or

```
$('#CustomizeBuy').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.QuickOrderForm.action ="customize-order.cfm";
    $('#QuickOrderForm').submit();
   parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
});
```

Comment: Did you try `('#formID', top.document).submit();`? top or parent...

Answer (score 0):

Is the iframe of the same domain as the window? ie localhost&localhost poo.com&poo.com

As far as I've experimented you cannot perform Javascript on an iframe from a different domain for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, the iframe content is in the same domain.